# HTTP interface for Android application

Tags: java, android, http

Hi: I want to implement a http remote control for an Android application: From a browser on a computer in the local area network the application running on the Android device should be controlled.

Are there any recommendation how to implement this? I heard about i-jetty but it is not uncomplex to integrate it into an existing app.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to implement an HTTP remote control interface for a *desktop* program and use the Android *mobile* device to remote control it?

Comment: The idea is to make no requirements to the desktop side, beside a web browser. The application on the device should then be configured remotely from the desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're going to run into here are:

1. Android devices are mobile. They do not have a fixed IP address or DNS address. You'd need to implement some sort of discovery service.
2. Android devices move between networks, and some networks will have NAT. You won't always be able to contact the device.

My advice here would be to use the new Android C2DM service and push a command down to the device telling your application that there's a request waiting. Once the notification arrives, have your application contact a web server at a known address to see what the request actually is.

In other words, you'd be running an intermediary web server that proxies requests on behalf of your Android device.

More information about C2DM can be found here:

http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/